# PassengerEnabled Off and Password Protect Directory using .htaccess with Django on Dreamhost

Tags: django, .htaccess, passenger, dreamhost

I have a website built using Django on Dreamhost deployed successfully with Passenger and Apache. I have a set of static HTML pages that is being served in a remapped sub-directory called `/demo/`. By adding a `.htaccess` file to the `/demo/` directory with this line:

`PassengerEnabled off`

I was able to bypass Django and serve the static pages in the `/demo/` directory. I would like to add password protection to the `/demo/` pages without editing the Django python files, but was unable to do so by adding the following lines to the `.htaccess` file (both above and below the `PassengerEnabled off` line:

```
AuthUserFile /public/demo/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Private Demo Area"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

I am not forced to use the `.htaccess` file approach and was wondering how do I configure the static file directory to not be processed by Django but also be password protected? Thanks!

Comment: Why again is it that you don't want the static file directory not to be served through Django? Django's settings.py file (in your main Django directory) allows for the static folder to be set.

Comment: I would prefer not to make any changes to the Django files already running. This is a demo application that will only be temporary so I am looking for a solution that involves not altering those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which involved creating a subdomain instead of trying to serve the static files through Django and Passenger through a remapped sub-directory. Here is what I did:

- Created subdomain demo.domain.com in dreamhost web panel
- Added the .htaccess file to the root directory of the subdomain:

  AuthUserFile /public/demo/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null
  AuthName "Private Demo Area"
  AuthType Basic
  require valid-user

That did the trick, but the domain for my demo is now `demo.domain.com` instead of `domain.com/demo/`. I am ok with this trade off and this was the only solution I could find on dreamhost shared hosting.